# Making title stay put after buttons change height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a page that I'm trying to animate. What happens right now is that when the page loads, the header fades in and moves up. After that, every time the user hovers over a button, the button changes color and height. The problem is that every time the button changes height, the text above it (the title ) also moves up. How do I prevent this from happening?

Apart from giving the solution, any tips on removing redundant code or other style tips would be appreciated.

```css
.nav-button {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  border: 0.1em solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 1.7em;
}
    
#apply-button {
  background-color: #28A55C;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
    
#apply-button:hover {
  background-color: #DF1C40;
  height: 2.4em;
}
    
#about-button {
  background-color: #97BBDD;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
    
#about-button:hover {
  background-color: #DF1C40;
  height: 2.4em;
}
    
#sponsor-button {
  background-color: #FF9D28;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
    
#sponsor-button:hover {
  background-color: #DF1C40;
  height: 2.4em;
}
```

```html
<!-- intro page -->
<div id="splash" tabindex='1'>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <strong>DubsTech</strong>
            <br>
            Students teaching Students
            <br>
        </div>
        <button class="nav-button" id="apply-button">Apply!</button>
        <button class="nav-button" id="about-button">About</button>
        <button class="nav-button" id="sponsor-button">Sponsor</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to that all three buttons are sibling elements of "title" element. Any layout changes make their common parent element "#header" changes. One solution would be using another wrapper "div" to wrap all these buttons and set this wrapper "height:2.4em" so that height transition of buttons won't affect "title".